# Mac OS X 10.6, Xcode 4, PowerPC C compiler?

Tags: macos, xcode, gcc

When I try to cross-compile C code for PowerPC, I get the following error:

```
llvm-gcc-4.2: error trying to exec '/usr/bin/../llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/powerpc-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2': execvp: No such file or directory
```

What is the best way to install the missing compiler?

Comment: Just a guess, but reinstall Xcode and check all checkboxes when asked what you want to install?

Comment: Is the PowerPC compiler still part of Xcode?

Comment: That's why it's a guess. Start the installer and check the options.

Comment: Also, since there's no Xcode 5, you haven't actually told us the version you're using ;)

Comment: dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333490

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode 4 does not include the PPC tools BUT you can migrate them over from an Xcode 3 installation with a little bit of work. There was a site detailing how but I can't find it. If you really need to work with PPC I'd recommend running Xcode 3 though.

Also, I don't know your situation, but I'd strongly recommend moving away from PPC support unless you really truly need it. Just my opinion though.

Comment: It's really for my own purposes. I still have PowerPC machines.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333490/how-can-we-restore-ppc-ppc64-as-well-as-full-10-4-10-5-sdk-support-to-xcode-4)

And then do this in addition (edit paths as needed):

```
cd /Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/bin
ln -s /Developer3/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/powerpc-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2 powerpc-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2
```

Answer (score 0):

[XcodeLegacy](https://github.com/devernay/xcodelegacy) is a too that installs older OS X compilers and SDKs on more recent versions of OS X / macOS.

This tool tells you which Xcode packages you need to download, and then extracts the compilers and SDKs from the Xcode distributions and installs them.